# re-display all form input before post

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Before some people start yelling, I realize there is similar questions up, but their all dealing with single entries...

I have a long form and want to use a generic method of dealing with the re-displaying of data.
Please note : this is an asp.Net MVC 4 application using razor2 views

Example of one of the fields,

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @name = "nameInput" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My think was to add an ID to each Textbox...
Example of how is might be displayed on the confirmation view..

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="text display-value" data-display="nameInput"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then render that value using data-display with the ID...

jQuery that I thought would deal with it...

```
var displayConfirm = function() {
    $('.display-value', form).each(function(){
        var input = $('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-display")+'"]', form);
        if (input.is(":text") || input.is("textarea")) {
            $(this).html(input.val());
        } else if (input.is("select")) {
            $(this).html(input.find('option:selected').text());
        } 
    });
}
```

Unfortunately this does not appear to be working correctly....
Can anyone point out / re-solve the issue ?

Comment: This may not make a world of difference, in this scenario. But I have run into cases where it has for me on the occasion. Where you define `var input = `... try `var $input = ` ... then change it respectively through out so `input` is `$input`. Again, not saying its going to help 100% or even at all, but for some reason I can't remember I know there are cases where using the `$` with a var is helpful in working with jQuery. I think its extending it in a sense or something to that effect

Comment: also, depending on your jQuery version try `.prop` instead of `.attr` or you can try the `.data`. you could also try `.display-value :input').each(`... and `$(this)` instead of `$('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-display")+'"]', form);`

Comment: Many thanks chris, however none of the above has had any effect... I put an alert on the method just to be sure and it is firing when it should....so back to the drawing board I go.....

Comment: Got it, I needed to use the name in the model rather then assigning names.
Got correct names from "page view source", and simply plugged that value into data-display tag.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I needed to use the name in the model rather then assigning names.

Got correct names from "page view source", and simply plugged that value into data-display tag.